# ClassCastException while integrating socialauth 4.7 and socialauth-spring 2.6 with spring 4

Tags: spring-mvc, socialauth

I am trying to integrate socialauth 4.7 and socialauth-spring 2.6 with Spring 4.0.0 and tomcat. I am able to do "clean install" but getting following exception while running tomcat. Are these version compatible?

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

Below is my pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
    <unitils.version>3.1</unitils.version>

    <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
    <org.springframework.security.crypto-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.crypto-version>
    <spring-social.version>1.0.3.RELEASE</spring-social.version>
    <org.springframework.social-facebook-version>1.0.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.social-facebook-version>

    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    <context.path>MyDreamHome</context.path>
    <base.dir>MyDreamHome</base.dir>
    <spring.social.version>1.1.0.M4</spring.social.version>
</properties>




<dependencies>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.brickred</groupId>
        <artifactId>socialauth</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.brickred</groupId>
        <artifactId>socialauth-spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security.crypto-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JdbcUserConfiguration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.159</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
        <artifactId>unitils-core</artifactId>
        <version>${unitils.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
        <artifactId>unitils-easymock</artifactId>
        <version>${unitils.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
        <artifactId>unitils-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${unitils.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Manually deployed the generated war file on tomcat 8 and it worked. Probably issue was in tomcat to which maven was deploying the war file.